# If a message is there, but you cannot see it, is it really there?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have created a space encoder program, because it is fun to generate invisible messages. (This programme is **not** cryptographically secure, it is just for fun)

```
import doctest

def to_spaces(text):
    """
    Each char with ASCII code x gets converted to a
    line of x spaces.

    >>> to_spaces('a').count(' ')
    97
    >>> to_spaces("hello").count(' ')
    532
    """
    return '\n'.join((' '*ord(char) for char in text))

def from_spaces(spaces):
    """
    Each line of x spaces gets converted to the
    char of ASCII code x.

    >>> from_spaces(' '*97)
    'a'
    """
    return ''.join((chr(len(i)) for i in spaces.splitlines()))

def encode_and_print_file():
    filename = input("Where do you want to save the encrypted text? ")
    content = input("Enter your secret message: ")
    with open(filename,"w+") as f:
        f.write(to_spaces(content))

def decode_and_print_file():
    filename = input("Which file do you want to read decoded? ")
    with open(filename) as f:
        print(from_spaces(f.read()))

def user_interface():
    while True:
        choice = input("\nDo you want to encode or decode? ")
        encode_and_print_file() if 'en' in choice.lower() \
                                else decode_and_print_file()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    doctest.testmod()
    user_interface()
```

Comment: Seems fine. And fun. I could only suggest cosmetic changes to pass PEP8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Coding style looks good except for one thing. You are using a conditional expression where an `if` statement would do.

  ```
  encode_and_print_file() if 'en' in choice.lower() \
                          else decode_and_print_file()
  ```

  As the value of the expression is not used, I would prefer the statement version as it is clearer:

  ```
  if 'en' in choice.lower():
      encode_and_print_file()
  else:
      decode_and_print_file()
  ```
- I don't see why you use `if 'en' in choice.lower()` to recognize the word "encode", allowing "en" anywhere. `if choice.strip().lower().startswith('en')` would be more to the point.